# Swift - Chain inheritance for classes to init objects

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, casting

I have a top level class called *AbstractItem* and which contains some fields as follows:

```
class AbstractItem: NSObject, AbstractItemDelegate  {

 var challengeImage = UIImage()

 var numberOfParticipants:Int = 0
 ...
```

Now, I have another class *ChallengeItem* that inherits from *AbstractItem*

```
class ChallengeItem:AbstractItem, Codable {

let challengeDataAccessService =  ChallengeDataAccessService()
...
```

and a third class that inherits from *ChallengeItem*

```
class ChallengeInfoItem:ChallengeItem {

}..
```

I can easily cast AbstractItem to ChallengeItem. However, when I try to cast AbstractItem to *ChallengeInfoItem*, it fails. Same issue when trying to cast *ChallengeItem* to *ChallengeInfoItem*.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This sounds like it might be an XY problem. That being said, you can do a *conditional* cast -- eg `if let narrowedItem = abstractItem as? ChallengeInfoItem { }`

Comment: Hi @jnpdx, I tried your approach. I am wondering why it doesn't go into the if block. Looks like the cast doesn't work properly. Do you have further hints for me? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it has to do with you changing the specs of the object along the way. Namely AbstractItem doesn't conform to `Codable`, while ChallengeInfoItem has to conform to Codable. So not every AbstractItem is suitable to be ChallengeInfoItem. If that's the case, move `Codable requirement down the chain (to AbstractItem) as easiest fix probably.

Comment: A conditional cast works fine (even with `Codable` from the above comment). I just tested some sample code in a Playground to make sure. Therefore, my current theory is that your item is not in fact a `ChallengeInfoItem`, although I certainly could be wrong. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: Hello @jnpdx thank you soo much. Indeed, my item was not `ChallengeInfoItem`but `ChallengeItem'` This solved the problem